# Inserting Timeline Items Using Mirror API Playground?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I've been playing around with the Mirror API playground for Google Glass.  The templates at the bottom are great with helping you get started.  I've created a ClientID through my Google APIs console and added that to my playground instance.

I read through the timeline developers guide and am a little lost on how to insert an item onto the timeline.  Can I post to the timeline using the sandbox input area on the playground page?  I've tried a few variations of code I found on the docs, but nothing shows up on my timeline.  I am also not sure how the blue 'Insert Item' button relates to the whole sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the playground correctly, but it may be inserting cards into the wrong account's timeline.

If you've created an API Console project with the Google Mirror API enabled, authenticated, clicked the blue "Insert" button, and no errors are displayed, the playground did insert a card somewhere.

Here are the troubleshooting steps I'd follow:

1. Open an incognito or private browsing window.
2. Go to https://developers.google.com/glass/playground.
3. Paste your client ID into the playground and authenticate.
4. The pop-up will ask for your Google account credentials. Supply the credentials for the account that you're using on Glass.
5. Insert a card into your timeline.
6. Wait a minute and double-check your timeline. Most of the cards on timeline do not trigger an audio notification at the time of insert. They are inserted silently.

Comment: Hi Jenny, I followed the steps laid out above.  The only thing I changed was the default text that popped up in the input box before I hit the insert item button.  There doesn't seem to be any problems with the insert button since I didn't see any error messages after pressing it.  I waited for about 5 minutes, but still don't see anything on my timeline?

Comment: Are other Glassware synchronizing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.  I don't actually have a pair of Glass.  Is the playground dependent on having a pair of Glass?

Comment: Yup. You need Glass to enable the Mirror API and you need to have the Mirror API enabled to use the insert function of the playground.

Comment: I guess I'll bunker up and wait it out then :)

Comment: @JennyMurphy Can you please explain why do most of the cards don't trigger the sound notification? Can the card be somehow configured to trigger it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an unofficial implementation of MirrorAPI available here at [Scarigami Mirror API emulator](http://glass-apps.org/google-glass-emulator) which comes with a browser based emulator.